# How to prove the relation $R$ is a function?

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

**Definition:** The relation $R ⊆ A \times B$ is a function only if it satisfies the two properties:

1. For every $x∈A$ there is $y∈B$ s.t. $x\mathrel{R}y$;
2. if $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $x\mathrel{R}z$ then $y=z$.

**The question:**
*Prove that $R ⊆ A \times B$ is a function if and only if $\ker(R)$ is an equivalence relation.*

**Note:** $\ker(R) = R^{-1}\circ R$, the composition of $R$ inverse and $R$.

---

I already proved that $\ker(R)$ is an equivalence relation, by proving for the relation the reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties.

But I'm having trouble on how to prove that $R$ is a function.

Comment: Show that it is either one-to-one, onto, or both.

Comment: Could you please share with us the definition you have been given of $\ker$ of a binary relation? It is clear what it must be for a function, but on top of my head I can think of a few sensible generalizations to relations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @MatthewDaly You're right.  My bad.

Comment: @Gae.S. Ker(R) = R^-1 o R, the composition of inverse R and R

Comment: For this to be true $\ker(R)$ has to be an equivalence relation *on all of $A\times A$*. But that doesn't work well with the notation that $\ker(R) = R^{-1} \circ R$, which to my mind should be a relation on a subset of $B \times B$. ($b\ R^{-1}\circ R\ c$ if and only if there is an $a \in A$ such that $ b\ R^{-1}\ a$ and $a\ R\ c$). Apparently you are using a different notational convention, where $R^{-1}$, though on the left, acts on the element on the right, and $R$, though on the right, acts on the element on the left??

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm confused, what is your question?

Comment: I assume that $R^{-1}$ is the reverse of $(a,b) \in R \iff (b,a) \in R^{-1}$. But exactly what definition are you using for the composition? I.e. if $R\subseteq A\times B$ and $Q \subseteq B \times C$, do you denote the composition as $R \circ Q$ or $Q \circ R$, and exactly how are you defining it? I ask because there is a disconnect between what I see in your question and what I would expect.

Comment: @PaulSinclair for example S={(1,6),(2,1),(4,0)} , R ={ (1,1) , (1,2), (2,5), (3,4).   
S o R = {(1,6), (1,1), (3,0)}

Comment: @PaulSinclair S o R = { (a,c) | for every b∈B (aRb and bSc ) }

Comment: I certainly hope it is not "for every", or else for $(a,c) \in S\circ R$ would require $a$ to be related to all of $B$ by $R$ and all of $B$ to be related to $c$ by $S$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair b can be changed, in the example I gave we assign b =1 then b =2 then b= 4 so basically all the y's of the R relation

Comment: @PaulSinclair Take a look at this, R = { (0,1), (0,2) } is a relation (R ⊆ {0} × {1,2}), and is obviously not a function from {0} to {1,2} (since it maps 0 onto two different values) so R isn't a function according to this since it doesn't satisfy the 2nd condition in the definition above. Can this be correct?